# how to check if javafx application is already running programatically?

Tags: java, javafx

i'm trying to run a javafx application from a thread outside the scope of the application class. Th problem i'm using a while loop to generate the application and it throws an illegalstatexception whenever it is called twice, so i need a way to distinguish if the application is already running to continue with my other tasks, any ideas?

Comment: I didn't think you could run any javafx components on another thread other then it's main event thread

Comment: Why do you want to check whether you application is already running ? Do you want to run just one instance of the application ?

Comment: You could create a file whenever you start your application and check for existance...

Comment: @Inge or create a boolean variable and set it to true when your JavaFx application is launched

Answer (score 1):

Based on @nejinx 's answer, you have to do this when calling Application.launch():

```
try {
    Application.launch(args);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {}
```

That way, if the error happens, your program will just keep running and not try to start the application again.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyServer implements Runnable{

    public static final int PORT = 99 ;

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private Window window;

    public MyServer(Stage window) throws AlreadyBoundException {

        if(serverSocket!=null && !serverSocket.isClosed())
            throw new AlreadyBoundException("The server is already running.");

        this.window = window;

        try( Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", PORT);) {

            Platform.exit();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            final Thread thread = new Thread(this);

            thread.setDaemon(true);
            int priority = thread.getPriority();

            if(priority>Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
                thread.setPriority(--priority);

            thread.start();
        }
 }

public void run() {

     try {
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, 1);
         while (true) {
           Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
           clientSocket.close();

           Platform.runLater(()->window.requestFocus());
         }
     }catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Error in MyServer: " + e);
     }
 }
```

}

And in the JavaFX APP:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    // Start server
    new MyServer(stage);

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is to catch the IllegalStateException

If you dig down into the JavaFX source code you see this:

```
if (launchCalled.getAndSet(true)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Application launch must not be called more than once");
}
```